# For loop producing unexpected results in C

Tags: c, loops, for-loop, cs50

I just started doing the cs50 course but having trouble with the first problem sheet. The aim is to produce right aligned steps (steps you use in Mario just before finishing the level and jump on the flag pole).

The code I have written produces the steps but not right aligned.

But why does my code produce the steps? Shouldn't the condition for the second for loop always be false since i = j when the second for loop is executed?

Sorry if this has been answered before but I'm having trouble articulating my question.

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <cs50.h>

int main(){

    int height = get_int("How tall are the pyramids: ");

    for (int i = 0; i < height; i++){
        printf("##");

        for (int j = 0; j < i; j++){
            printf("#");
        }
        printf("\n");
    }
}
```

Comment: But `j = 0` is zero when the second for is encountered.

Comment: Please add actual and expected outcomes.

Comment: Hint: print spaces to align on the right

Comment: There's a [cs50 stack exchange](https://cs50.stackexchange.com/) if you're interested.

Comment: @KamilCuk Doesn't j increase by 1 before i increases by 1? because the j loop is inside the i loop

Comment: @dbush Thank you! I'll try it out in a bit but my main question is why the second for loop is ever executed at all

Comment: @KernelPource On the first iteration of the outer loop it won't, but it will on later iterations when `i` is greater than 0.

Comment: @pmg Thank you I'll check it out, but question was a general C question about for loops

Comment: `for (int j = 0; j < i; ++j)` is the same as `int j = 0; while (j < i) { ... ++j;}` Rewrite both for's and see the differents. The first time it doesn execute, but the second time it executes onces. Then twice. And so on.

Comment: @KernelPource see how for loop is executed here https://www.tutorialspoint.com/cprogramming/c_for_loop.htm. The loop for `j` on future runs, still start with `j = 0` because that's initialization step for inner loop

Comment: @KamilCuk The syntax is still a big confusing but I get it now, thanks!

Comment: @vinayawsm The explanation I was looking for!! Thanks!!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Copy and paste this into codechef.com/ide using GCC 6.3.  There are a few sample pryamids, left right center both upside down and right side up.  To answer your specific quesiton, j is assigned to 0 in the second (nested) for loop, so j is not = to i at the start of the loop.

```
#include <stdio.h>
int main(){

    int height = 10;//get_int("How tall are the pyramids: ");

    printf("regular left justified\n");
    for (int i = 0; i < height; i++){
        printf("##");

        for (int j = 0; j < i; j++){
            printf("#");
        }
        printf("\n");
    }

    printf("Upside down left justified\n");
    for (int i = height; i >0 ; i--){
        printf("##");

        for (int j = 0; j < i; j++){
            printf("#");
        }
        printf("\n");
    }

    printf("upside down centered pryamid\n");
    for (int i = 0; i < height; i++){
        //printf("##");

        for (int j = 0; j < i; j++){
            printf(" ");
        }
        for( int j=i; j<height; j++){
            printf("##");    
        }
        printf("\n");
    }

    printf("regular centered pryamid\n");
    for (int i = 0; i < height; i++){
        //printf("##");

        for (int j = height; j > i; j--){
            printf(" ");
        }
        for( int j=height; j>=height-i; j--){
            printf("##");    
        }
        printf("\n");
    }

    printf("regular right justified\n");
    for (int i = 0; i < height; i++){
        //printf("##");

        for (int j = height; j > i; j--){
            printf(" ");
        }
        for( int j=height; j>=height-i; j--){
            printf("#");    
        }
        printf("\n");
    }

    printf("upside down right justified\n");
    for (int i = 0; i < height; i++){
        //printf("##");

        for( int j=height; j>=height-i; j--){
            printf(" ");    
        }

        for (int j = height; j > i; j--){
            printf("#");
        }

        printf("\n");
    }

}
```

Answer (score 2):

Good attempt; however, you'll need to print a series of spaces before your steps in order to produce right-alignment. This isn't necessarily obvious since the spaces are invisible (and unnecessary for a left-aligned triangle).

The formula for the number of  spaces to print is `height - row_number - 1`, and the formula for the number of step characters to print is `row_number + 1` (or `column_number <= row_number`). I recommend experimenting with these numbers and attempting to produce different patterns which will help your understanding. The reason for the extra `-1`/`+1` offset is to avoid printing a blank line above the triangle.

To answer your question about your second loop termination condition, it'll only be false once you've printed a number of step characters less than the row number, while the first loop is the inverse of this.

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <cs50.h>

int main() { 
    int height = get_int("How tall are the pyramids: ");

    for (int i = 0; i < height; i++) {
        for (int j = 0; j < height - i - 1; j++) {
            printf(" ");
        }

        for (int j = 0; j <= i; j++) {
            printf("#");
        }

        printf("\n");
    }
}
```

Output (height = 10):

```
         #
        ##
       ###
      ####
     #####
    ######
   #######
  ########
 #########
##########
```

[Try it!](https://repl.it/repls/CulturedMetallicBinary)

Comment: This has been bugging me for so long! I'll try to remake it with your hints then check back. I appreciate the help!

Comment: May I suggest using `"  "` (two spaces) and `"# "` as it makes a nicer looking triangle.